# C++ link of two nodes between two classes

Tags: c++, class

I am stuck with this problem. Given the frame code

```
class P
{
public:
    class C1
    {
    public:
        class D
        {
        public:
            int data;
            D* next;
            typename C2::D* link;
            
            D(int data)
            {
                this->data = data;
                this->next = NULL;
                this->link = NULL;
            }
        };
        D* first;
        void add(int data);
    };

    class C2
    {
    public:
        class D
        {
        public:
            int data;
            D* next;
            typename C1::D* link;

            D(int data)
            {
                this->data = data;
                this->next = NULL;
                this->link = NULL;
            }
        };
        
        void add(int data);
    };

public:
    C1* c1 = new C1();
    C2* c2 = new C2();
    void add(int data);
};
```

When I call the add function of class P, two add functions of class C1 and class C2 are executed to create two new nodes with given data, for each class C1 and C2. The problem is that I want the node in C1 contains the address of the corresponding node in C2, and similarly (by the pointer link). Could anybody give me an idea, pls?

Comment: Why declare two completely distinct classes that are identical? The point of a class is to define how it works, and then you can create distinct objects from it.

Comment: may be, you need forward declaration (class c2;). but what task are you trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

I have some concerns about the design. I'd just use the standard containers and allow them to duplicate the data as needed, and avoid using any raw pointers. But that's up to you.

To answer the question, you need to declare your node class once, and then it knows how to declare a pointer to itself. A class is a type, which means all instances work exactly the same. Similarly, C1 and C2 are identical so I don't see any reason to declare them as distinct types, so I took the liberty of merging them as well, although you really only have to do that with your node type (which needs to know what the node type is).

By hiding all this within P, we can create the nodes and their cross-pointers in P::add, treating that as a factory constructor.

```
class P
{
public:
    class D
    {
    public:
        int data;
        D* next;
        D* link;

        D(int data)
        {
            this->data = data;
            this->next = NULL;
            this->link = NULL;
        }
    };

    class C
    {
    public:
        D* first;
        void add(D* node);
    };

    // encapsulate in P
    C* c1 = new C();
    C* c2 = new C();

public:
    void add(int data) {
        // encapsulated in P so we can create the raw pointers
        D* D1 = new D(data);
        D* D2 = new D(data);
        D1->link = D2;
        D2->link = D1;
        c1->add(D1);
        c2->add(D2);
    }
};
```

The core problem you have is that you don't know all the node types before they are declared, which is fixed by making them all one type. I can imagine that you do have reasons for them to be distinct types, and if so, then you might have to declare an abstract base class for the nodes, which is a whole new topic. Or you could just declare the collection and node class once, and create subclasses that are identical. I can edit to do that if you need.